# Inheritance with QGraphicsItem and QGraphicsLineItem

Tags: c++, qt, inheritance, qgraphicsitem

I have a class, that inherits QGraphicsItem and this class needs to be inherited by another class that inherits QGraphicsLineItem and QGraphicsTextItem. When I do this it gives me the error class Line has no member named setLine

Following is the whole scenerio explained:

getEntity.h

```
#ifndef getEntity_H
#define getEntity_H

#include <QGraphicsItem>

class getEntity :public QObject , public QGraphicsItem
{

public:
    getEntity(QObject* parent=0) : QObject(parent) {}
    virtual ~getEntity() {}

    virtual getEntity* my_clone() { return 0; }
};


#endif // getEntity_H
```

line.h

```
//This is my class that needs to inherits gEntity

    #ifndef LINE_H
    #define LINE_H

    #include <QPainter>
    #include <QGraphicsLineItem>

    class Line : public QObject, public QGraphicsLineItem
    {
        Q_OBJECT
    public:
        Line(int, QPointF, QPointF);
        QRectF boundingRect() const;
        virtual void paint(QPainter *painter,
                           const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                           QWidget *widget);
        enum { Type = UserType + 2 };
        int type() const;
        int id;

        QPointF start_p, end_p, move_p, check_p;

    private:
        QVector<QPointF> stuff;
    };

    #endif // LINE_H
```

line.cpp

```
#include "line.h"

Line::Line(int i, QPointF p1, QPointF p2)
{
    // assigns id
    id = i;

    // set values of start point and end point of line
    start_p = p1;
    end_p = p2;
}

int Line::type() const
{
    // Enable the use of qgraphicsitem_cast with line item.
    return Type;
}

QRectF Line::boundingRect() const
{
    qreal extra = 1.0;

    // bounding rectangle for line
    return QRectF(line().p1(), QSizeF(line().p2().x() - line().p1().x(),
                                      line().p2().y() - line().p1().y()))
            .normalized()
            .adjusted(-extra, -extra, extra, extra);
}

void Line::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionGraphicsItem *option,
                  QWidget *widget)
{
    // draws/paints the path of line
    QPen paintpen;
    painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing);
    paintpen.setWidth(1);

    if (isSelected())
    {
        // sets brush for end points
        painter->setBrush(Qt::SolidPattern);
        paintpen.setColor(Qt::red);
        painter->setPen(paintpen);
        painter->drawEllipse(start_p, 2, 2);
        painter->drawEllipse(end_p, 2, 2);

        // sets pen for line path
        paintpen.setStyle(Qt::DashLine);
        paintpen.setColor(Qt::black);
        painter->setPen(paintpen);
        painter->drawLine(start_p, end_p);
    }
    else
    {   painter->save();
        painter->setBrush(Qt::SolidPattern);
        paintpen.setColor(Qt::black);
        painter->setPen(paintpen);
        painter->drawEllipse(start_p, 2, 2);
        painter->drawEllipse(end_p, 2, 2);
        painter->drawLine(start_p, end_p);
        painter->restore();
    }
}
```

cadgraphicscene.cpp

```
//Here it returns pointing to setLine method, when I inherit getEntity in Line class
 if (mPaintFlag)
            {
                lineItem = new Line(++id, start_p, end_p);
                lineItem->setLine(start_p.x(), start_p.y(), end_p.x(), end_p.y());
```

How the Line class can correctly inherit getEntity? Do help!

Comment: Why are you inheriting from QObject?

Comment: I am using the concept of signals and slots:/

Comment: Not in the code you've shown. You can't multiply inherit from QObject. I don't understand at all what you're trying to achieve with this code, but looks like you have a design problem. Multiple inheritance is a pretty complex tool to use. Maybe if you described exactly what you're trying to achieve, someone could point out a saner approach.

Comment: I want to have the cut, copy paste opertaions in my GraphicsView. I have different classes for all my entities, inherited from Graphics Item and QGraphicsLineItem and GraphicsText Item. I am using getEntity class to clone the properties of all the entities.

Comment: To use signals and slots, putting `Q_OBJECT` (as you did in the class `Line`) is enough.